# VBA regex and group

Tags: regex, vba

applying the below regex on below email body:

```
(pls[a-zA-Z0-9 .*-]*) \(([A-Z 0-9]*)\)
```

email body:

```
pls18244a.lam64*fra-pth (PI000581) 
pls18856a.10ge*fra-pth (PI0005AW) 
pls25040a.10ge*fra-pth (IIE0004WK) 
pls27477a.10ge*fra-pth (WL050814) 
pls22099a.stm4*par-pth (PI0005TE)
```

returns 5 match, with two groups. what is the VBA script to get groups in each match using using incremental variable to copy each match groups in excel row?

Comment: `match` objects have a `submatches` collection, so you'd loop over that for each match.

Answer (score 21):

Not making any changes to your regular expression pattern. Using the following way, you can iterate through the groups of each match:

```
str="pls18244a.lam64*fra-pth (PI000581)pls18856a.10ge*fra-pth (PI0005AW)pls25040a.10ge*fra-pth (IIE0004WK)pls27477a.10ge*fra-pth (WL050814)pls22099a.stm4*par-pth (PI0005TE)"
Set objReg = New RegExp
objReg.IgnoreCase=False
objReg.Global=True
objReg.Pattern = "(pls[a-zA-Z0-9 .*-]*) \(([A-Z 0-9]*)\)"
Set objMatches = objReg.Execute(str)
For Each match In objMatches             'The variable match will contain the full match
    a= match.Submatches.Count            'total number of groups in the full match  
    For i=0 To a-1
        MsgBox match.Submatches.Item(i)  'display each group
    Next
Next
Set objReg = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks, (for each)sentence should be contains matches  instead of match..
and i need to get 1stmatch.1stgroup  and 1stmatch.2ndgroup and so on .. in separated fields?

Comment: please could any one assist on this?

Comment: I didn't get what you are saying? You have the whole working code now. It is displaying both the groups of each match. Do you want to display the whole match?