# Non-capturing groups do not work properly to extract Backreferences number ( 1 and 2)

Tags: regex, vba

Basically I need to extract specific digits from my string depend on the below pattern. 
I have used non-capturing groups to discard some matched string from the end result, But it does not work. 
I need to extract only Backreferences number ( 1 and 2) and (if possible put a space between) to parse it later using vba `Split` function.

| String | Current output | Expected Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC Cat 2 RAP 15 efh 20 | Cat 2 RAP 15 | 2 15 |
| ABC Cat3 RAE8 efh 30 | Cat3 RAE8 | 3 8 |

```
Function cat(strInput As String) As String

    Static re As New RegExp

     With re
       .Global = True
       .MultiLine = True
       .IgnoreCase = True
     End With
     
     re.Pattern = "\b(?:Cat)(?:\s)*([1-5])(?:\s)*(?:RA)(?:[SPE])(?:\s)*([0-9]){1,2}\b"
    
    If re.Test(strInput) = True Then
      cat = re.Execute(strInput)(0)
    End If
    
End Function
```

Comment: Could you simply replace matches of `^\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)` with `'\1 \2'`?

Comment: So your regex already get the group values that you want right? You can get the group values like this [VBA regex and group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44401036/vba-regex-and-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not need to use non-capturing groups. Instead, you can simply use capturing groups for the parts of the pattern you are interested in, and then access those matched groups. Something like:

```
' ...rest
    re.Pattern = "\bCat\s*([1-5])\s*RA[SPE]\s*([0-9]{1,2})\b"

    If re.Test(strInput) = True Then
        Dim matches As MatchCollection
        Set matches = re.Execute(strInput)
        cat = matches(0).SubMatches(0) & " " & matches(0).SubMatches(1)
    End If
' ...rest of code
```